# Excel: Saving Selected Worksheets into PDF file

Tags: excel, pdf, save, add-in, worksheet

Although this questions was already asked I did not find a real answer for it.
I need to programmatically select worksheets in a workbook and save them to PDF file WITHOUT creating temporary workbook and copying selected worksheets to it.

Alternatively how do create workbook without displaying it - that is, in memory and then on HD? This is again may help to solve the first question...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub SaveToPdf()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim sfName As String

For Each ws In Worksheets

sfName = ws.Name
sfName = "C:\Misc\" & sfName & ".pdf"

        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        sfName, Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next ws


End Sub
```

You'd need to make sure your print areas on each sheet were set first I think

Comment: I don't this it works - actually I am sure it does not - how it knows what SELECTED worksheet in the workbook to print? This code prints worksheet as a separate PDF and it is not my question. May be you should read it again...

Comment: The code works for saving ALL worksheets as separate pdf files.  Do you want to save multiple worksheets to a single pdf?  Or are you looking for a way to dynamically select a single worksheet to save to pdf?  If you always want to save the same worksheet(s), you could add an "if" statement into the code to check if the name matches the one you want.